# Trying to render cylinder in three.js, failing with err "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a large three.js code, and when I add a simple cylinder to it it crashes the renderer:

```js
    const lineGeometry = new Three.CylinderBufferGeometry(1.0, // radiusTop
                                                          1.0, // radiusBottom
                                                          1.0, // height
                                                          7, 1) // radial/height segments
    this.line = new Three.Mesh(lineGeometry, material)
    this.add(this.line)

    // ... later ...
    viewer.render()
```

The crash is during render, in [WebGLRenderer.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ca5b01b43b16e7ecc3c2676314889170831f7fb7/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L790) in `renderBufferDirect` (actually `renderer.setIndex`), and seems to be caused by the fact that this geometry has an `index` property. The code in three.js WebGLRenderer.js where it crashes is this:

```js
        if ( index !== null ) {
            attribute = attributes.get( index ); // this returns undefined
            renderer = indexedBufferRenderer;
            renderer.setIndex( attribute ); // attribute is undefined here, causes crash
        }
```

and the failure is due to `attribute` being undefined. The geometry itself only has attributes `position`, `normal` and `uv`, but I'm not sure that's why it's failing.

I tried to cut this down, but of course in a small example it works fine. :-(

It looks like `index` is a valid set of indices into the `position` array:

```
index: Uint16BufferAttribute {name: "", array: Uint16Array(84), itemSize: 1, count: 84, normalized: false, …}
attributes:
position: Float32BufferAttribute {name: "", array: Float32Array(138), itemSize: 3, count: 46, normalized: false, …}
normal: Float32BufferAttribute {name: "", array: Float32Array(138), itemSize: 3, count: 46, normalized: false, …}
uv: Float32BufferAttribute {name: "", array: Float32Array(92), itemSize: 2, count: 46, normalized: false, …}
```

so I'm not sure what `attributes.get(index)` is supposed to be doing, and what I need to feed it so it'll work. Any help appreciated!

This is with three.js r111 btw.

Comment: In a working cut-down example, the line `attribute = attributes.get(index)` returns an object containing a `WebGLBuffer` that looks like a representation of the index array. So what have I screwed up that would make that fail?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out, sort of. My `lineGeometry` has a duplicate `buffergeometry.id`, so the it gets skipped in `WebGLObjects.update()` and never updated. As for how I got a duplicate ID, that's still to be figured out.

Comment: I had two copies of three.js -- one being imported and 'rollup'ed by a submodule, and the other imported by my module. So they were fighting over the IDs.